# Is it possible to use modestbranding with youtube-api?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to load a video onto my page using Youtube API.

Youtube specifies that you can enable 'modest branding' (ie. removing youtube logos) by appending the parameter '&modestbranding=1' to the embed url.

The problem I'm having is that the new youtube API embeds the video using javascript eg:

```
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: videoHeight,
    width: videoWidth,
    videoId: videoID,        
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
```

This then generates the relevant iframe script, however I'd like to be able to specify modest branding within these parameters. I tried adding an extra parameter:

```
modestbranding: 1
```

and

```
modestbranding: '1'
```

but neither seems to have any effect.

I realise that one option would be to grab the embed url from the final rendered script and then append the parameter onto the src:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="player" title="YouTube video player" height="368" width="640" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<id>?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

However I would've thought youtube would somehow allow to specify the parameter rather than having to use some dirty hack.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`modestbranding` is a player var and thus should be added with the `playerVars' attribute.  Details can be found on the developer docs.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Here's an example on how to include `modestedbranding` or other player vars.

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  playerVars: {
    modestbranding: true
  },
  height: videoHeight,
  width: videoWidth,
  videoId: videoID,        
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I couldn't find anything when I was looking! Poor searching technique :-)

Comment: Youtubeplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
        {
            height: "100%",
            width: '100%',
            videoId: videoid,
            playerVars: { autoplay: 1, showinfo: 0, playsinline: 1, autohide: 1,controls: 0, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 1, fs: 0, modestbranding: true, rel: 0,start: ytinit,end: ytend},
            events: 
            {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

Comment: using that it is not working for me, maybe it has been removed by youtube?

Answer (score 2):

After some testing

If you set showinfo to 0 then you get the youtube logo even if modesbranding is true.

There is no way to leave the video fully clear it seems.

This will show the logo but not the title

```
    Youtubeplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
    {
        height: "100%",
        width: '100%',
        videoId: videoid,
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1, controls: 0, modestbranding: true, showinfo: 1
        },
        events: 
        {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
```

This will show the title but not the logo

```
    Youtubeplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
    {
        height: "100%",
        width: '100%',
        videoId: videoid,
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1, controls: 0, modestbranding: true, showinfo: 0
        },
        events: 
        {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
```